# Debug and Release Issue

Tags: c, embedded

Summary:
A 10-character message is sent through the interface (It uses RS485). Then, the first character, "h," is received by the processor and verified. If it is confirmed to be the character "h," the remaining 9 characters are received. After verifying the accuracy of the received 9 characters, they are sent back to the interface for two-way verification. If the 9 characters are verified by the interface, the software parses the firmware file and sends it to the processor. The processor writes the parsed software to the specified section in the flash memory. After the processor restarts, the bootloader software runs first, and then, after 1 second, it jumps to the flash memory area where the parsed main software is loaded and starts runningç However these code works for only debug ly debug mode. When I loaded the Release mode, GUI interface cahth the nothing from microporessor.

Ii tried many things. Decrease or increase microprocessor's frequency. Receiving 2 times the character of the received message and finding the desired message from the received characters etc.

```c
  while (1)
  {

      //check to recieve mode
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(iap_lib.rs485_gpio, iap_lib.rs485_DR_pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
        HAL_UART_Receive(iap_lib.rs485_uart, receivedmessage, 1, 1000);

      if (receivedmessage[0] == 'h')
      {
        HAL_UART_Receive(iap_lib.rs485_uart, receivedmessage, 9, 1000);
        status = strcmp(receivedmessage,hello_message);

            if (status == 0){
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(iap_lib.rs485_gpio, iap_lib.rs485_DR_pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                HAL_UART_Transmit(iap_lib.rs485_uart, receivedmessage, 9, 1000);
                HAL_Delay(1000);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(iap_lib.rs485_gpio, iap_lib.rs485_DR_pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                Ymodem_Receive(&file_size, iap_lib);
                }
            else
            {/* Keep the user application running */
                        main_app();
            }
      }

      else if (receivedmessage[0] == 'r')
      {
        HAL_UART_Receive(iap_lib.rs485_uart,receivedmessage, 9, 1000);
        status2 = strcmp((char *)receivedmessage, reset_comsett_message);
            if (status2 == 0)
            {
                uint32_t new_ID = 0xA5000201;
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(iap_lib.rs485_gpio, iap_lib.rs485_DR_pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
                HAL_UART_Transmit(iap_lib.rs485_uart, receivedmessage, 9, 1000);
                HAL_Delay(1000);
                uint32_t sourceAddress = 0x0800FC00; // Start address of the desired flash page
                uint32_t destinationAddress = (uint32_t)destinationArray; // Get the address of the destination array
                copyPageToStruct(&IDPage);
                writeStructToFlash(&IDPage);
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(iap_lib.rs485_gpio, iap_lib.rs485_DR_pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            }

            else
            {/* Keep the user application running */
                 main_app();
            }
      }
```

Comment: What MCU? STM32? Which one?

Comment: Is `receivedmessage` containing a null terminator or is one appended before passed to this code? Otherwise that's the bug.

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the reamining 9 characters if the first one is not `'h'` or `'r'`? Do you receive and discard them? Or do you treat the next character as the new first character.

Comment: You never check the return value from `HAL_UART_Receive()`. It might be returning `HAL_ERROR` or `HAL_TIMEOUT`. Or something else.

Comment: @Lundin MCU is STM32F030C8Tx. Okay I will add the null terminator and try again.

Comment: @Gerhardh if the first character is not 'h' or 'r' it will be nothing. If it can't catch the specified characters, it needs to run the main application.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I check the receive message in debug mode it is okay but in release mode I transfer the message it has received to an interface with UART, message is not correct. However you are right but maybe as Lundin said null terminator might broke the code.